# Least Squares and Weighted Least Squares

Tags: regression, estimation, least-squares

I'm fine with the least squares derivation:

$e = Hx-z$

$e^2 = ||Hx-z||^2$

$\hat{x} = \text{argmin}(e^2)$

...

$\hat{x} = (H^TH)^{-1}H^Tz$

However, for the weighted least squares derivation, my notes introduce it like so:

$e^2 = ||R^{-1}(Hx-z)||^2$,

where R is the covariance matrix of of uncertainty of each measurement. Expanding like so:

$e^2 = (Hx-z)^TR^{-2}(Hx-z)$,

and minimising, I get:

$\hat{x} = (H^TR^{-2}H)^{-1}H^TR^{-2}z$,

where all the $R^{-2}$ should be $R^{-1}$ as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7NQo.png).

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: What do you want to get? Your derivation is fine, and you got the WLS estimator.

Comment: I can't work out where the discrepancy between the linked notes and my derivation comes from, i.e. the power of $R$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo in the linked version. If $e \sim N(0, R )$., then it should be
$$
R^{-1/2}(Hx - z),
$$
because 
$$
Var(R^{-1/2}(Hx - z))=R^{-1/2}Var(z)R^{-1/2}= R^{-1/2}R^{1/2}R^{1/2}R^{-1/2} =I.
$$